# Is “I bind round” correct to say?

Tags: grammar, american-english

I saw this translation on Wikipedia for diadem from Greek to English: “The word derives from the Greek διάδημα diádēma, "band" or "fillet", from διαδέω diadéō, *"I bind round"*, or "I fasten"”.

Is it grammatical?

Is it like saying “I fly high”?

What type of grammar is it using?

Thanks

Comment: Explaining where a word came from does not involve producing a good result in the target language, only showing the origins of the source parts.

Comment: @YosefBaskin but shouldn’t the translations be grammatical? That’s what I’m asking, if it is, not whether it’s good or bad.

Comment: You are asking about the beauty of the etymology of the English word Diadem, not translation. No, the explanation of how we got here does not have to give us good English.

Comment: *Bind* is normally transitive, so you could say "it doesn't have an object so it's not grammatical" but that's completely missing the point. If you're actually wanting to use *round* in a similar way in your own sentence, tell us your sentence and why you want to write it. If you want more information on the etymology, say (but consider asking in Latin SE, which covers ancient Greek.) If you're just nitpicking dictionaries because you don't like them, then likewise tell us and we can dish some salacious gossip.

Comment: I think the comments are missing the point.  The question is whether *I bind round* has the same structure as *I fly high*.

Comment: It needs an object. You _bind_ a [fillet](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fillet) _round_ your own, or someone else's, head.

Comment: @YosefBaskin now you’re telling me what I’m asking…

Comment: I bind round is not grammatical in English. I bind up is, for example.

Comment: A lot of the agita on this question seems to be from people taking "is this grammatical" to mean "is this a grammatical sentence". And the answer to the latter is "No. It's a translation of an isolated word, not a translation of a sentence". Honestly, I'm not sure enough of it to make it an answer, but "No. An incomplete sentence fragment is neither grammatical or non-grammatical" might be a good response.  Another good response is "You seem to want to know if this has a valid usage, and what is its meaning, not 'is it grammatical'".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When citing a verb in Greek or Latin, the custom is to take the first Principal Part of the verb as its name. In both Greek and Latin, the first principal part of a verb is its first person singular present tense form, the one translated with *I* for subject:

- Latin *amō, amāre, amāvī, amātus* 'love'
  ['I love', 'to love' (active infinitive), 'I have loved' (perfect tense), 'loved' (past participle)
  Here we'd just call the verb *amo* (or *amare*)

As Wikipedia puts it,

> Verbs in Ancient Greek have six principal parts: present (I), future (II), aorist (III), perfect (IV), perfect middle (V) and aorist passive (VI), each listed in its first-person singular form.

That means that whatever Greek word we've chosen as the name of the verb, it'll be first person singular. Hence the *I* of διαδέω *I bind round*.

Yes, it's grammatical. It means nothing -- it's just a citation form -- but it's certainly grammatical. It's so grammatical that every Greek verb is cited with a subject *I*.

Comment: Really? It is grammatical? I make use of literal translations into/in English to make a point all the time but I don't see this as grammatical **in English** at all. To bind x round y, yes. To go/come round [to someone's house]. Also.

Comment: It's grammatical in the context given. The convention is to cite the first person, and not to worry about phrasal verbs in other languages.

Comment: Ahhhhh. In Greek. Sure. I had no way of knowing you were referring to the Greek.

Comment: So to be clear, "I bind round" is a faithful translation into English, but outside of this context it's not grammatical in English on its own? But something like PaulTanenbaum's "I bind round your head of a crown of flowers" gives a grammatical useage? I'm going to accept this as it gives me the most context.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question . . . or at least, I already recognized that this was the citation form, yet I still don't know the answer to the question. What does "to bind round" mean?

Comment: @JKusin My problem is with bind followed by round. The "I" doesn't give me any problem. Bind round would always make me go "what?". Bind around as an intransitive might be OK.

Comment: @JKusin P.S. you have an extra "of" in your quote of PaulTanenbaum.

Answer (score 7):

I don’t know Greek, so  can’t address the accuracy of the translation. But *I bind **round*** does have a grammatically correct reading. For example, the sentence

> I bind round your head a crown of flowers

expresses a claim by the speaker to be fastening the crown around the head of the addressee. And probably fairly snugly; that’s often implicit in the use of *bind*.

*Round*, like its synonym *around*, is a preposition. And it’s use is not at all limited to contexts involving the verb *bind*.

I would also note that there is a jazz standard by Thelonius Monk called *’Round Midnight*. His choice to include that initial apostrophe suggests that he heard *round* as a casual shortening of *around*.

Comment: Can you tell me what part of speech it is? Is it similar to my other example? Is it only acceptable with to bind?

Comment: I’ve edited my answer to give it’s syntactic category.

Comment: Are you saying that 'round' remains an (intransitive) preposition in the standalone 'I bind round'? // Glosses often sound stilted; 'Ich dien' loses quite a lot in the translation, and sounds weak even for say Roger Federer or Ivo Karlovic.

Comment: No, @EdwinAshworth, I  make no claim about *I bind round* as a complete, stand-alone utterance. As you note, its occurrence in the OP is as a gloss, and for the purposes of the question, I interpreted it only as a fragment.

Comment: Tim interprets it as an IP here, in line with CGEL, no doubt.

Comment: The other order of this: I bind a crown of flowers round your head  IS NOT: bind round. bind round on its own is not a phrasal verb or anything else, in fact. I just do not get people here.

Comment: 'I bind round' is arguably unacceptable as a standalone sentence (it's a faithful gloss of the Greek). But it's fair game as an inscription, as are many non-sentence structures. 'Is it grammatical?' comes close to asking 'Is 'The Scream' grammatical?'  We're dealing with structures that can be found in longer strings, but are (syntactically) too short for there to be a meaningful answer to the question.

Comment: I’m inclined to agree with you, @EdwinAshworth. But I wasn’t prepared to make the unqualified assertion that it’s not a valid English utterance. Anyway, I definitely agree about the meaningfulness of assessing small fragments outside of any larger structures.

Comment: Is "I fasten your head a crown of flowers" grammatical? (the alternate translation)

Comment: @JKusin, I *guess* it’s grammatical, but I **know** it’s nonsensical. For starters, usually one fastens a thing **to** another thing. Furthermore, fastening often involves staples, nails, screws, or other such *fasteners* that perforate—or pass through perforations in—the thing being fastened to. Ouch! If one fastened a crown **around** (or **round**) someone’s head, then any perforations would be restricted to the crown itself, so no problem there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **I bind round** is an independent clause with an intransitive verb in the first person singular.  **round** is a variant of **around**.

**round** is also intransitive there, a preposition.

If a radio could itself talk, it might say *I send over*.

What does a detour do?  It *circumvents*.

What does a cook do? A cook gathers and measures and mixes and stirs, and rolls up and dries off and de-veins and scrambles and tosses; a cook watches and smells and tastes.

What does a nomad do? -- A nomad wanders around.

What does a sheepdog do? -- A sheepdog rounds up.

What does an accountant do? -- An accountant rounds up.

**When transitive verbs are used with a subject but without an object it is a way of referring to the abstract essentials of the verb *in action*.**

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148593/discussion-on-answer-by-timr-on-a-different-device-is-i-bind-round-correct-to). Comments continuing discussion may be removed.